# Changing perspective in AS3 - fp9

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

Does anyone know the equivalent of using the perspectiveProjection property on a displayObject but in flash player 9.

The PerspectiveProjection class was only bought in in fp10 but 9 also renders a scene in perspective when 3d transforms have been applied to objects.

In fp10 this works..

```
var pp:PerspectiveProjection = new PerspectiveProjection();
pp.projectionCenter = new Point(stage.stageWidth/2, 40);
_closedHolder.transform.perspectiveProjection = pp;
```

I need an equivalent which can target flash 9?

Comment: I was pretty sure this isn't supported until FP10.  IF you need FP9 support, you'll have to investigate usingone of the 3D frameworks, such as Away3D.

Comment: So is it right that fp9 supports native 3d but not fully? It seems to publish fine and allows Z to be set and give perspective, but the app doesn't function correctly when the stage is resized.

Comment: It depends how you define fully.  I don't think "Full Native 3D" would be available until Stage3D/Molehill comes out in FP11.

Comment: Flextras is right, you can't do this with Flash Player 9 without using a 3rd party 3d library.  I recommend you close the question.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com - if you want to add your answer will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APIs you want to access are not supported until Flash Player 10.  Full Native 3D will not be supported until Flash Player 11; with the introduction of STage3D / Molehill.

IF you need support in Flash Player 9; then you should investigate using one of the 3D frameworks, such as [Away3D](http://away3d.com/) or [PaperVision3D](http://blog.papervision3d.org/).  I'm pretty sure Away3D is the currently preferred one; as development has halted on PaperVision.